# Interpreting a string into code ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a list

```
let myList = ["Animals"; "Cat"; "Tiddles"; "Dog"; "Rover"]
```

and I am trying to create a function that will read this data and return an object like so:

```
Animals([Cat("Tiddles"); Dog("Rover")])
```

So far I have something like this:

```
let rec readList = function
    | hd :: tl -> readString hd tl
and readString hd tl =
    match hd with
    | "Animals" -> Animals([readList tl])
    | "Cat" -> Cat("...")
    | "Dog" -> Dog("...");;
```

which results in

```
Animals([Cat("...")])
```

What I need to know is how I can pass the next item in the list to the Cat object and then add a semi-colon and call readList tl so the dog can be added next

It might look something like this

```
| "Cat" -> Cat(x); readList tl
```

where x is the next item in the list ("Tiddles") and tl contains the rest of the list ("Dog", "Rover"). However I know that the semi-colon will mean that only readList tl is returned so it won't work like that

Basically I want to be able to recursively add objects to the Animals list using the data in the list. Apologies if it is not explained clearly

Answer (score 1):

I would start by carefully thinking through the types of your functions.

As a more detailed observation, in this expression:

```
Animals([readList tl])
```

The list inside `Animals(...)` will always have exactly one element in it. Whatever value is returned by `readList tl` will be the one element of the list.

It's more likely you want to code something like this:

```
Animals(readlist tl)
```

However, this would mean that `readlist` cannot return `Animals(...)` as a result, since it isn't a list.

This is why I say you should perhaps start by thinking through the types of things. You might need to reorganize your set of functions.

You're thinking about a semicolon as something that adds an element to a list, but that's not a particularly good way to think of OCaml lists. The OCaml operator for making a list is `::`. It takes a single element at the left and a list at the right, and returns a list with the new element at the beginning.